# Does histogram_summary respect name_scope

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting a Duplicate tag error when I try to write out histogram summaries for a multi-layer network that I generate procedurally. I think that the problem might be related to naming. Imagine code like the following:

```
with tf.name_scope(some_unique_name):
  ...
  _ = tf.histogram_summary('weights', kernel_weights)
```

I'd naively assumed that 'weights' would be scoped to some_unique_name but I'm suspecting that it is not. Are summary names independent of name_scope?

Answer (score 3):

As [Dave points out,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761189/3574081) the `tag` argument to `tf.histogram_summary(tag, ...)` is indeed independent of the current name scope. Part of the reason for this is that the `tag` may be a string `Tensor` (i.e. computed by part of your graph), whereas name scopes are a purely client-side construct (i.e. Python-only), so there's no good way to make the scoping work consistently across the two modes of use.

However, if you're using TensorFlow build from source (and should be available in the next release, 0.8.0), you can use the following recipe to scope your tags (using [`Graph.unique_name(..., mark_as_used=False)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.unique_name)):

```
with tf.name_scope(some_unique_name):
  # ...
  tf.histogram_summary(
      tf.get_default_graph().unique_name('weights', mark_as_used=False),
      kernel_weights)
```

Alternatively, you can do the following in the current version:

```
with tf.name_scope(some_unique_name) as scope:
  # ...
  tf.histogram_summary(scope + 'weights', kernel_weights)
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you - I suspected that name_scope was not really part of the graph. I did log a bug on GitHub but I guess it is not a bug after all. It is a wee bit of a bummer to have to carry scope around everywhere. May I ask what kind of name unique_name constructs?

Comment: It applies the exact same logic that is used when you pass `name="foo"` as an argument to an op constructor. (i.e. It appends `"foo"` to the current name scope and possibly adds `"_1"`, `"_2"` etc. to make it unique within the current scope.) If this turns out to be usrful, we could make a utility method that makes it easier to access.

Answer (score 1):

They are.

I'm with you in thinking this is a bug, but I haven't run it past the designers of the op yet.  Go ahead and open an issue for it on GitHub!

(I've run into this also and found it terribly annoying -- it prevents reuse of the model without deliberately parameterizing the summary op invocations.)

Comment: I quickly added a unique name layer to my code and the Duplicate tag bug went away so that was definitely why it happened.